# Why is my webGL context returning as null, but also showing that it was retrieved?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm starting on webGL and I'm a little confused about something.  I'm getting the context in a try/catch and I'm actually showing that the try is successful, however, I'm also showing that my context is null.  Can anyone explain to me why this is?  According to the tutorial, I should be seeing a black box, but I'm not.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <canvas id="webGL" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    start();
    var gl;//Holds the WebGL context
    function start(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById("webGL");
        gl = initWebGL(canvas);//Initializes the GL context
        if(gl){
            gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);//Sets the clear color to black
            gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);//Enables depth testing
            gl.depthFUNC(gl.LEQUAL);//Near things obsure far things
            gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);//Clears the color and depth buffer
        }
    }

    function initWebGL(canvas){
        gl = null;
        try{
            //Tries to grab the standard context.  If it fails, fallback to the experimental version
            gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
            console.log("Got it");
            console.log(gl);
        }
        catch(e){
            //If there is no GL context, give up
            if(!gl){
                gl = null;
                console.log("You suck");
                console.log(gl);
            }
        }
        return gl;
    }
})
```

Here's my [pen](http://codepen.io/RobbyT15/pen/GZrEjg) to see what's actually happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your are calling `depthFUNC` when you should call `depthFunc`

Comment: Thanks for that, but that didn't actually fix the problem

Comment: i can now see the black box you were talking about

Comment: Ah, there it is, had to clear my cache.  Thanks very much.